# DIY hydrolysis of starch with copper and test them with polarizer sheet due to muta rotation

Tags: chirality, hydrolysis, optical-properties

When I read about muta rotation — the interconversion of alpha to beta glucose — recently, I decided to do it with rice, because rice contain 66% of starch which is alpha glucose polymer. To hydrolyze the starch in rice, normally chemists use HCl-like acid as catalyst, but in my home there is nothing like that so I thought about copper, because I’ve seen that copper is used as catalyst in most cases. Will it work? I.e.,

(Cu) starch + H2O --->  alpha_D_glucose

Does the above reaction work? (We can see with polarizers due to chirality.)